# \footnotetext in a \caption indented different than \footnote

Tags: tables, captions, footnotes, adjustwidth

I have to put a footnote in the caption of a table and of a figure. Due to the fact that using \footnote it just display the number but it doesn't show the tex in the footnote part, I used:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{Figures/2.PNG}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\caption[]{exapmple caption\footnotemark }
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{example text I want in the footnote}.}
```

The problem is that in this way the footnote I have from \footnotetext is different from the normal one I have using \footnote.

[image: Differences in footnote]

As you can see, footnote 72,73, 74 are the ones from \footnote{}, while footnote 74 is the one of \footnotetext.

In the code, \footnote is

```
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
        \oldfootnote{%
            \vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{adjustwidth}{5,5pt}{0pt}{#1}\end{adjustwidth}
            \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        }%
}%
\makeatother
```

I would love that the \footnotetext would not differentiate from the other \footnote and I would appreciate your help in indentation it or in finding a way to place \footnote in \caption.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a complete, self-contained [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the outpu you get?

Comment: You redefine only  `\footnote` and not `\footnotetext`.

Comment: Assuming there is a `\let\oldfootnote=\footnote` in there, `\oldfootnote` calls `\footnotetext`, so if you modify `\footnotetext` you WON'T need to modify `\footnote`.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying. There is a \let\oldfootnote\footnote, however, I am struggling modifying in the code the \footnotetext function because I cannot add it to \let\oldfootnote\footnotetext and even if renew the command \footnotetext does not work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I know I just redefine \footnote, how can I also redefine footnotetext in the same way?